# Count concurrent occurrences of overlapping times, down to the second, across multiple dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with the following structure

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 18/11/2022 15:09:39 | 18/11/2022 15:09:54 |
| 18/11/2022 15:09:10 | 18/11/2022 15:09:24 |

I am looking for a formula that will count the concurrent occurrences that overlap down to the second. It should be a count for each set of overlaps.

i.e., take below example data

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 18/11/2022 14:57:09 | 18/11/2022 15:07:15 |
| 18/11/2022 15:06:02 | 18/11/2022 15:07:07 |
| 18/11/2022 15:03:10 | 18/11/2022 15:03:26 |
| 18/11/2022 15:02:52 | 18/11/2022 15:03:05 |
| 18/11/2022 14:58:31 | 18/11/2022 14:58:44 |
| 18/11/2022 14:27:50 | 18/11/2022 14:56:38 |
| 18/11/2022 14:52:21 | 18/11/2022 14:54:11 |

The first 5 rows overlap with each other, so that is 5 concurrent overlaps
the last 2 rows overlap, but not with the first 5, so that would be a new count of concurrent overlaps.

The data goes over multiple days, so this needs to be considered in the solution

Multiple days data

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| 18/11/2022 9:59:27 | 18/11/2022 10:00:07 |
| 18/11/2022 9:49:51 | 18/11/2022 9:53:21 |
| 18/11/2022 9:38:16 | 18/11/2022 9:46:59 |
| 18/11/2022 9:45:37 | 18/11/2022 9:45:45 |
| 18/11/2022 9:41:44 | 18/11/2022 9:42:14 |
| 18/11/2022 8:34:01 | 18/11/2022 8:34:44 |
| 18/11/2022 8:11:46 | 18/11/2022 8:13:58 |
| 18/11/2022 8:08:46 | 18/11/2022 8:09:41 |
| 17/11/2022 19:18:47 | 17/11/2022 19:18:54 |
| 17/11/2022 18:50:49 | 17/11/2022 18:51:11 |
| 17/11/2022 17:40:20 | 17/11/2022 17:40:45 |
| 17/11/2022 17:00:04 | 17/11/2022 17:03:48 |
| 17/11/2022 16:58:35 | 17/11/2022 16:58:50 |
| 17/11/2022 16:54:31 | 17/11/2022 16:57:55 |
| 17/11/2022 16:34:01 | 17/11/2022 16:34:29 |
| 17/11/2022 16:32:30 | 17/11/2022 16:33:31 |
| 17/11/2022 16:28:23 | 17/11/2022 16:32:59 |
| 17/11/2022 16:30:38 | 17/11/2022 16:30:57 |
| 17/11/2022 16:22:10 | 17/11/2022 16:22:27 |
| 17/11/2022 15:51:36 | 17/11/2022 15:51:48 |
| 17/11/2022 15:48:10 | 17/11/2022 15:48:49 |
| 17/11/2022 15:40:22 | 17/11/2022 15:40:46 |
| 17/11/2022 15:30:32 | 17/11/2022 15:36:44 |
| 17/11/2022 15:33:11 | 17/11/2022 15:34:30 |
| 17/11/2022 15:32:05 | 17/11/2022 15:33:14 |
| 17/11/2022 15:23:27 | 17/11/2022 15:32:31 |

I have tried a few examples that seem to only deal with days but don't go to the seconds level.

Comment: What would be your desired output from given table?

Comment: a list of those concurrent counts is fine.
Can call it max concurrent or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you want to display the result, you can have different options. I am assuming the following one, if not please **update your question** about the expected output for the sample data you provided. *Assuming no excel version constraints as per the tags listed on the question*.

```
=LET(starts, A2:A27, ends, B2:B27, MAP(starts, ends, LAMBDA(s,e,
 SUM((starts <= e) * (ends >= s))-1)))
```

It indicates on each interval, the total number of overlaps. Here is the output:

[image: excel output]
General logical condition to check if two intervals `A`, and `B` overlap is the following:

```
AND(startA <= endB, endA >= startB)
```

In our case, we are comparing a given start (`s`) and end (`e`) on each iteration of `MAP` with the entire column `starts`, and `ends`, since each interval overlaps with itself, we need to subtract `1`.

Comment: thanks for this. looks to be what I need. I applied it but I dont get the same output as you! It only shows the first cell and not anything under that.
Do I need to apply the formula to other cells too?
Thanks

Comment: It is an array formula. It spills the entire result, not just the first cell.  Are you sure you are doing the same? Check it. Do you have O365? Just checking.

Comment: got it!! Sorry I hadn't realised it was an array formula.
It's perfect. Thank you

Comment: Just to add for people who are not excel experts: Type in the formula and press strg+shift+enter instead of enter, so the formula is created as array formula.

Comment: @BernhardLaven this is valid for old Excel versions, it is not required for Office 365 to use Shift+Enter, it is natively incorporated.